# Every natural less than 40 can be written in the form $2^mb$ with $b$ less than $21$

Tags: combinatorics

I am reading a book on combinatoric methods and in one of the examples it is stated that any $n \in \{1,...,40\}$ can be written in the form $n=2^mb$, where $1\leq b \leq 21$. Isn't this false? For example I don't see how $39$ can be written in this way seeing that it is odd and greater than $21$. The book used this result to prove using the pidgeonhole principle that any subset of $21$ elements of $\{1,...,40\}$ has two elements such that one divides the other, maybe something similar to what the book states is true and can be used to prove the same result?

Comment: Any even one can.  Maybe the word even got left out.

Comment: For the divisibility question, put any two numbers such that one is a power of $2$ times the other into the same pigeonhole. So $1,2,4,8,16,32$ are in one hole, $3,6,12,24$ in another, and so on. There is a pigeonhole for every odd number $\le 39$, so $20$ of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re paraphrasing it accurately, it is indeed wrong. What it should say is that every $n\in\{1,\ldots,40\}$ can be written in the form $n=2^mb$, where $m$ is a non-negative integer, and $b$ is an odd integer less than or equal to $39$. There are just $20$ such odd integers, so two of members of $\{1,\ldots,40\}$ must share the same odd factor in this decomposition, and one must therefore be a multiple of the other.